# Popper.js: how to determine if popper is too big for the boundary

Tags: javascript, typescript, popper.js

I would like to know if there is a way to determine if the Popper element is too big for the boundary? Maybe in the `onCreate` callback?

The problem i am facing is: I would like to align the left side of the Popper element to the left side (indicated by the red arrow) of the black boundary border, however, when I specify the boundary in the `modifiers.preventOverflow.boundariesElement` option, because the popper is too big in height for the boundary, it messed up the placement.

[image: need left placement to the boundary]

this is how it looks like after i set the `modifiers.preventOverflow.boundariesElement` option to the black border.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example